# Account Billing Address Picklist without State and Country Picklists

Tags: page-layout, country-and-state, address

I'm trying to replace the Standard BillingCountry field on the Account with a picklist, but it seems I can't remove the standard field and replace it with a custom picklist - does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

I don't want to use the State and Country picklist functionality as this makes the state field useless for a global company without doing a very large amount of work trying to define all the possible states for a large amount of countries (and I believe also the functionality starts failing at around 1000 values anyway).

A validation rule to make sure the country value matches a predetermined list also seems like overkill, and is not a good user experience (Would also mean that the list of countries in the validation would have to be replicated for all address fields).

This seems like something that should be possible, but I just can't find a way of doing it reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the billing address standard field from the account page layout and add your custom picklist field with the necessary validations for achieving this requirement

Comment: I don't seem to be able to remove just the country field though - in the layout all the address fields are grouped under 'Billing Address' so can't remove just one

Comment: yes you can't just remove the 'billing country' field all the related fields will be removed  you can just create the custom fields which you need for this particular requirement

Comment: Thanks, though I'd have to do this for all standard address fields (Account, Contact, etc), which feels like a very cumbersome solution